# SecurityError: Error #2142: Security sandbox violation

Tags: apache-flex

When I want to load my asset inside my Flex project I got this error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2142: Security sandbox violation: local SWF files 
cannot use the LoaderContext.securityDomain property. 
app:/Main.swf was attempting to load app:/assets/stories/bear.swf.
```

I created a LoaderContext and assigned it to SWFLoader but I still get this error. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:ns1="*"
               applicationDPI="240" creationComplete="initApp(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
            import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

            protected function initApp(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
                context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
                context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();

                Story.loaderContext = context;
                Story.source = "app:/assets/stories/Bear1.swf";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:SWFLoader id="Story" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
                 trustContent="true"
                 scaleContent="true"/>
</s:Application>
```

I read a lot about Security Policy in Flex but I still did not figure it out how can I allow local access to my app.

Comment: this problem have not proper solution. but by trick u get rid of this..

Comment: @dev I can use @ Embded but I'm afraid the final SWF take longer to load, especially that my assets are very large.

Comment: have u tried swfloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is no need to use loaderContext. As this is a mobile project all assets are considered local. What I was doing wrong was placing the 'assets' directory outside the 'src' directory. Only directories inside 'src' directory get exported into the final project.

Answer (score 0):

You may get solution by using [this](http://www.bigspaceship.com/2010/03/flash-files-domains-and-security-errors-oh-my/) or [this](http://snipplr.com/view/35252/as3-loading-swf-files-crossdomain/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. These solution might work in Flash but they are not actually working in Flex. I don't want to load a cross domain file. I just want to load a local file. Providing LoaderContext or NOT providing bring out the same exception.